# Cleanup broken glass and debris

Tags: backyard

I had the back half acre of my lot cleared of brush and saplings.  There was an old shed that the previous owners left to rot.  It had fallen to the ground and there is now a lot of broken glass and small pieces of debris all over the ground.

Along with the debris, there's a lot mulch type of material.
I want to eventually plant grass.

What is the most efficient way to clean this up?

Is there maybe some sort of big rake that I can pull across the lot?

Comment: A local teenager is the most effective way to clean this up. Pay them well and provide gloves and  pizza.

Comment: A rake is also a good tool for this, operated by a teenager :)

Comment: Jeff's answer raises a good point. "I want to eventually plant grass" . **Eventually?** Is your goal here to ask about how to clean up debris, glass and mulch and then at some later time re-sod OR is it how to clean up and prep an area to be ready for sod or new grass seed?

Answer (score 1):

You could have it scraped with a small excavator and apply fresh, clean topsoil.  The best time to do this would be early-spring.  Then you can plant grass seed right away.  When I've done this in the past, it took a couple months to grow and look nice.  Doing that for a half-acre will be expensive but if you only need to do it in the immediate area of the old shed it shouldn't break the bank.

Sod is another option depending on your budget.

If you don't care about getting rid of all the glass, sure, raking or whatever isn't a bad idea.  I'd start by using Roundup or similar to kill most of the existing vegetation to make that easier.  Then use a line trimmer & lawn mower as low as you can.

After that, consider if the raking is doing as good a job as you want; if not, rent a tiller and turn the soil over then re-compact it with a lawn roller (also easy to rent.)